# nslookup query not working in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dns, email

I am trying to use the code `nslookup -q=mx gmail.com` to find the mail server of gmail.com, but its not working on my Ubuntu. I have tried it in windows and it works fine. I can't find out what the issue on Ubuntu. The command `nslookup gmail.com` works though. Here are the responses of both commands;

**Response for**: `nslookup gmail.com`

```
thisisppn@thisisppn-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ nslookup gmail.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   gmail.com
Address: 216.58.196.5
```

**Response for**: `nslookup -q=mx gmail.com`

```
thisisppn@thisisppn-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ nslookup -q=mx gmail.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Looks strange though. Can you type just `nslookup` and enter, then type `set type=mx` and enter, now just try `gmail.com`. let me know whether that works?

Comment: i know right, I even tried it out on a live server, its working fine. And Regarding your suggestion. Here is the response which is same. `thisisppn@thisisppn-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ nslookup
> set type=mx
> gmail.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
> 
`

Comment: are you able to ping with an FQDN? what are your DNS servers? can you post an out put of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` & `route -n`.

Comment: @AzkerM here is the  output, I put it up on pastebin for better view. http://pastebin.com/akNAnNhM

Comment: @AzkerM Not sure what a FQDN is, as I am really new to Ubuntu and Linux systems. How can I find my DNS servers?

Comment: I'm not sure why the server ends with `1.1` where it should be `127.0.0.1`. Well, I might be wrong too. However, for the sake of testing,, can you do `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and comment the line `nameserver 127.0.1.1` starting with `#`.. also the same time add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` then save with `CTRL+O` and hit enter. Now remember! this is a temporary edit to see whether changing DNS responds to your query. [**FQDN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) refers to Fully qualified domain name which is commonly any domain names that not IP addresses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32239/discussion-between-azkerm-and-parthapratim-neog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick chat, I noted that the DNS entries causing you to resolve your queries. Adding **DNS** entries to `/etc/resolv.conf` made me clear that it is indeed the DNS.

Ways of adding DNS entries listed below.

## Adding additional entries to resolv.conf

Create a file under `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` as `tail` and add them there.

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

and add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` (or your preferred DNS). Once done, just restart the network manager with:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

## Adding through network-manager

Edit Connections -> select your network (wired/wireless) and **Edit** -> **IPv4 Settings** -> and select **Automatic (DHCP) address only** -> add under **Additional DNS servers**

Comment: Could you, by any chance, have an answer for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974037/shell-exec-empty-response-for-nslookup-query)?

Comment: Thanks @A.B. for the edit.. I was wondering how the hell did I miss that :D