# Wifi connected but no internet access (Lubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet

I have both wifi and lan connection to my pc, the wifi has internet and the lan connects me to other pc's on the home network.

If I unplug/disconnect the lan, the internet works, but when both wifi and lan are connected the internet works momentarily and then disconnects. I cannot open any website, even ping does not work here, for example "ping google.com" gives:

> ping: unknown host google.com

But I can ping the ip's on the internet, for example "ping 8.8.8.8" gives follows:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=110 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=98.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=101 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 98.492/103.462/110.263/4.983 ms
```

Output of Wireless info Script is as follows:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 01 Jan 2016 23:18 IST +0530

Booted last: 01 Jan 2016 22:31 IST +0530

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-55-generic #74~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 17 10:16:12 UTC 2015 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:07.0 Bridge [0680]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet [10de:03ef] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8234]
    Kernel driver in use: forcedeth

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rt2800usb              26712  0 
rt2x00usb              20041  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              83150  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              48886  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              563196  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              422935  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt              12627  1 rt2800lib
mxm_wmi                12893  1 nouveau
wmi                    18689  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11067 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15850 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:770753 (770.7 KB)  TX bytes:14862732 (14.8 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlan0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2434 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:604557 (604.5 KB)  TX bytes:350301 (350.3 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:4   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1057     1  0 22:31 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            forcedeth
  State:             connected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.100
    Prefix:          25 (255.255.255.128)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.2

    DNS:             192.168.0.2

- Device: wlan0  [Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994] ----------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rt2800usb
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           39 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    linksys:         Infra, <MAC 'linksys' [AC3]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA WPA2
    *Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994: Infra, <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 53 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.102
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Current Frequency=2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000075d57040d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 172ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'dlink-39D0' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"dlink-39D0"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000045f9e8938e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2884ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'linksys' [AC3]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-35 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"linksys"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000144ac5ea0b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 232ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rt2800usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2870.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 USB Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     80C4499E147864C0B13476F
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-55-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        CE:7D:DF:85:0B:DF:98:9C:CF:49:92:BB:EA:D0:EB:19:6E:A3:49:1D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2x00usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00usb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 usb library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     21417B97E30FD4E6E469E1F
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-55-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        CE:7D:DF:85:0B:DF:98:9C:CF:49:92:BB:EA:D0:EB:19:6E:A3:49:1D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Ralink RT2800 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
srcversion:     EDDCA794C9E4C3981037918
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211,crc-ccitt
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-55-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        CE:7D:DF:85:0B:DF:98:9C:CF:49:92:BB:EA:D0:EB:19:6E:A3:49:1D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     71EFA3CA86D02D0528C49EE
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-55-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        CE:7D:DF:85:0B:DF:98:9C:CF:49:92:BB:EA:D0:EB:19:6E:A3:49:1D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-55-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     477882071593B10E01388C8
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-55-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        CE:7D:DF:85:0B:DF:98:9C:CF:49:92:BB:EA:D0:EB:19:6E:A3:49:1D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-55-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     046346857FD53951C911443
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-55-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        CE:7D:DF:85:0B:DF:98:9C:CF:49:92:BB:EA:D0:EB:19:6E:A3:49:1D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rt2800usb]
nohwcrypt: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf]
blacklist visor

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10de:0x03ef (forcedeth)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rt2800usb)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   23.974692] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
[   24.003062] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5370 detected
[   32.941352] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[   33.083601] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
[   33.313855] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   33.318289] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0 eth0: MSI enabled
[   36.860352] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]>
[   36.898849] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   36.900438] wlan0: authenticated
[   36.904047] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   36.907662] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[   36.914154] wlan0: associated
[   36.914185] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   39.386661] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[   39.429725] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]>
[   39.448838] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   39.451964] wlan0: authenticated
[   39.456054] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   39.459305] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Tata-Photon-Max-Wi-Fi-4994' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[   39.465794] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Under Network Connection -> Wifi Connection
Used "Automatic (DHCP) address only"
Added 8.8.8.8 as Additonal DNS Servers

nslookup google.com

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
Added nameserver 8.8.8.8
sudo service network-manager restart

Still doesnt works.

Please note one correction on subject line, should be Lubuntu 14.04 instead of Ubuntu 14.04

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: This is due to the **DNS** that couldn't resolve **FQDN** properly.. Can you try the **Adding through network manager** option by looking at this -> http://askubuntu.com/a/703529/179042 .. let me know if it works

Comment: Sorry, still not working.

Comment: which one did you followed exactly?? can you post an output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: I actually did the changes both in network connections and /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail

Comment: That's the issue... I specifically said try the **Adding through network managet** option... Now, just do `sudo service network-manager resrtart` & check `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to see that you only seeing **8.8.8.8**... If so, try `ping google.com` and post back please

Comment: Actually I first tried adding through network manager, but it didnt work, so then I tried with the other option /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail provided in the url, that also didnt work either, I then kept both settings and still didnt work. Please note, I rebooted by pc between the changes. Now, I came across another url which says to comment dns=dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, I did it and now its working, should I expect any issue if I keep it like this?

Comment: It cannot be... This is definitely an issue with the **DNS*.. are you by any chance using static IPs?? Can you recall what exactly you did apart from what I have suggested?? are you still seeing two nameservers on you `resolv.conf` file?

Comment: no its dynamic actually, I only did the changes I have mentioned in the parent post above, just to keep track if I needed to undo anything. I came across a post which suggests to comment dns=dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, its working now, should I expect any issues if I keep this?

Comment: It would be better if you post as answer linking to the question that you have encountered explaining what you did. And accept it as your own answer :)

Comment: Just tried it again, just to be sure, Used "Automatic (DHCP) address only" Added 8.8.8.8 as Additonal DNS Servers, restarted network-manager and then cat /etc/resolv.conf returns only nameserver 127.0.1.1 and unable to open website, so removed all the changes  and commented dns=dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, it is working now

Comment: Thank you for your help and valuable time AzkerM :) Is there some way I can upvote you?

Comment: Not to worry & I'm glad you figured out yourself. Kudos to you.. Well, you kindness and satisfaction is more than what we require... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Followed the instructions given in the url [nameserver 127.0.1.1 in resolv.conf won't go away!](https://askubuntu.com/q/627899/488177)  and commented dns=dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and its working now

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solved by going into System Tools > Network. On the DNS tab I noticed a 172.* server I don't recognize. I replaced it with 8.8.8.8 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping an IP, but can't access a domain, that sounds like a problem with your DNS server. Try `nslookup google.com` to see if DNS lookup works. If not, [try changing your DNS server](https://askubuntu.com/a/2325/15600) to 8.8.8.8 (Google's Public DNS).

Comment: Done, but still doesnt works.